# How can I rename the current Xfce workspace from the command line?

Tags: xfce, workspaces

Currently I can change the workspace name by using the dialog. I am wondering where are these settings stored, if I can change them at runtime from the command line.

[image: Workspace Rename]

Comment: This program should do it, but it opens a window where you rename the https://github.com/ngeiswei/rename-xfce-workspace

Comment: Write a post so I can approve it please.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata Huh? you already accepted an answer that actually does not answer the question. You were asking about cli

Comment: **bogdan.mustiata** ----^ I have a method that works through the cli (probably the same one **@JacobVlijm** is thinking about)

Comment: @Fabby yep, no doubt;  gsettings blabla :) but please go ahead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This program](https://github.com/ngeiswei/rename-xfce-workspace) should do it, but it opens a window where you rename the workspace.